# Error storing instance of member function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++98, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to store a pointer to an instance of the member function template `Derived::initialize` as follows (see also [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/OWLM98035). For posterity, I've created a [simpler version](http://rextester.com/SZTK25211) of the problem.):

```
class Base
{
public:
    typedef void (Base::*setterFunction)( unsigned );

    template<unsigned N>
    struct SetterInterface
    {
        static Base::setterFunction Function;
    };

protected:
    template<unsigned N>
    void setterImpl( unsigned )
    {
    }
};

template<unsigned N>
Base::setterFunction Base::SetterInterface<N>::Function = &Base::setterImpl<N>;

class Derived : public Base
{
public: 
    typedef void (Derived::*Initializer)();

    template<typename T , void (T::*F)( unsigned ) >
    void initialize()
    {
    }

    template<typename C>
    Derived( C* )
    {
        Initializer initializer = &Derived::initialize<C, C::template SetterInterface<0>::Function>;    // NOT OK
        //Initializer initializer = &Derived::initialize<C, C::template setterImpl<0> >;    // OK
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived( (Base*)0 );
}
```

But I'm getting the error message on GCC 5.4.0 (and 6.4.0)

```
Test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived::Derived(C*) [with C = Base]’:
Test.cpp:45:28:   required from here
Test.cpp:37:39: error: no matches converting function ‘initialize’ to type ‘Derived::Initializer {aka void (class Derived::*)()}’
   Initializer initializer = &Derived::initialize<C, C::template SetterInterface<0>::Function>;
                                       ^
Test.cpp:30:7: note: candidate is: template<class T, void (T::* F1)(unsigned int)> void Derived::initialize()
  void initialize()
```

The problem appears to lie with the member function template argument because `C::template setterImpl<0>` works whereas `C::template SetterInterface<0>::Function` (which I suppose to be an alias to the former) does not. For example:

```
Base::setterFunction f1 = &Base::setterImpl<0>;
Base::setterFunction f2 = Base::template SetterInterface<0>::Function;
```

Comment: initialize() non type template parameter should be a constant expression; in your code it's a static member instead, so it cannot work; it could, if you declared it as static constexpr; anyway, what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `initialize()` *non-type-template-parameter* should be a constant expression; in your code it's a static member instead, so it cannot work; it could, if you declared it as *static constexpr* ( but you'd need at least a C++11 compiler then ):

```
class Base
{
protected:
    template<unsigned N>
    void setterImpl( unsigned );
public:
    typedef void (Base::*setterFunction)( unsigned );

    template<unsigned N>
    struct SetterInterface
    {
        static constexpr Base::setterFunction Function = &Base::setterImpl<N>;
    };
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to C++98/03. I'm amending the question tag to indicate this.

Comment: @olumide as it is, what you want seems not possible in c++03; that said, why don't you pass setterImpl directly ?

Comment: I can't because `setterImpl` has a different name in the other base classes (not shown) that `Derived` inherits. Therefore `SetterInterface::Function` attempts to create a generic name for these member functions.

Comment: @olumide do you mean that in the real code Derived is templetized over its base ?

Comment: No its not. It just inherits a bunch of derived classes that have different `setterImpl` (I'm using this name as a placeholder) functions with different names. Rather than rename all these `setterImpl`s and references to them I'm trying to wrap give a local alias to all these member functions. .... I suppose I could create per-class wrapper functions to call the implementations but an alias would be preferable.

Comment: The problem as I now see it is that "address of" is meaningless at compile time, pre C++11 at least.